# Nodejs: managing distributed transactions like java ee

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, distributed-transactions

One of the things that the Java enterprise platform facilitates is transaction management, and more so, distributed transaction management when multiple XA resources (database, message queues, resource adapters, etc)  are in play. 
Allowing for transactions to be rolled back should any particular participant fail for some reason.

Is there anything of that nature available for Nodejs?

I have searched but the only results that I have found thusfar has been related to database transactions and even then it seems to be more a case of letting the database handle the transaction management rather than at an application level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java EE is great choice for the requirements you have: distributed transactions management mechanism using multiple XA resources (database, message queues). Node is not (and in my opinion will never be) suitable for this.

Good example could be LevelDB database: you start with really basic functionality - just key-value storage, and you deliberately add functionality which you need, and not more. So the way is:

> from initial minimum -> to target solution (by adding, implementing)

In Java EE - you have huge all-in-one solution, and just pick what you need.
The way is:

> from initial all-in-one solution -> to target one (by removing, ignoring)

Neither of choices is a silver bullet, it just depends on your requirements.